# Zero number is always omitted in day section of Kendo-datepicker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, datepicker, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to input the following date:

```
5/01/2017
```

But the first zero of days is always omitted by `kendo-date-picker` and my date becomes the following:

```
5/12/17
```

HTML:

```
        <kendo-datepicker
            [min]="min"
            [max]="max"
            [(ngModel)]="value"
            #dateModel="ngModel"
        ></kendo-datepicker>
```

What I can do to not omit zero in days section to input days with zero?

This behavior can be seen [if you see DatePicker overview](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that is addressed in the `1.4.1` release of the `@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs`. More details can be found in the corresponding issue:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/910

The site is still using `1.3.1`, which has the described issue. Once the new release is used,

```
map: {
  ...,
  "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@1.4.1"
},
```

the component behaves as expected.

http://plnkr.co/edit/HonarK6ICLxhs221YHiY?p=preview